# Iterating an Interface

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write an iterator class for an interface class.

I've written the interface class something like this:

```
class Item;
class ItemList {
public:
    static ItemList* Create(void);
    virtual ~ItemList(void);
    virtual void AddItem(const Item& item) = 0;
    Item& GetItem(unsigned int index) = 0;
    unsigned int GetItemCount(void) const = 0;
};
```

The item class is also an interface.

```
class Item {
public:
    static Item* Create(void);
    virtual ~Item(void);
    Item* Clone(void) const = 0;
    int DoSomething(void) = 0;
};
```

I want to get rid of the `GetItem` and `GetItemCount` and use an iterator instead.

The problem is, I can't think of a way of doing that without keeping the `GetItem` and `GetItemCount` methods. I would like to know if there's a smart way of doing this before I try to hack something together.

Comment: Do you have any guarantees for how the actual data is stored, or is the interface agnostic entirely to that?

Comment: The data in the item? The interface is entirely agnostic to the `Item` implementation.

Comment: You should keep them: `GetItem` would be used when de-referencing the iterator and `GetItemCount` can be used to implement `size` and `empty`.  You could make them private helper methods.

Comment: I would keep them then and then bind a `size_t` for the current index and a `reference_wrapper<ItemList>`, and implement dereferencing via `GetItem`, and `it == end()` via the current index.

Comment: Well, there must be *some* way for the iterator to access the contents of the list. You could make those methods private and make iterator class a friend, but you can't get rid of them entirely; you'd still need them, or something substantially similar.